# Middleware between passport and angular

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, passport.js, middleware

First off, I'm very new to this. I'm writing a sails application with an angular front end and using passport for authentication. I would like to access the session data for the front end after a user has logged in. I've read multiple places that the data in the user object in api/policies/passport.js can only be accessed in a controller-served view, but I have no idea what would go inside this controller. All I have for this so far is the standard code inside api/policies/passport.js, assets/js/controllers.js, and assets/partials/partial1.html. So I don't have any code to show here. Can anyone show me an example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this tutorial to implement the passport.js authentication: https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/

After you've done that you can access to the season data in your homepage like this:

```
<html>

     Welcom back: 
     <% if(typeof user.username != 'undefined'){ user.username }%>
</html>
```

in the server side you can access the data like this:

```
index: function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
}
```

**Attach a controller to a view:**

in your sails/views folder create a new file called authHp.ejs.
In sails/controllers create a new controller called authHpController.js with this code:

```
module.exports = {

    index: function( req,res ){
        console.log("If you see this a request made to authHp.ejs and to his controller");
        res.view('authHp');
    }

};
```

Now go to config/routes and add this:

'/authHp': {
    controller: 'authHpController'
}

now it should be working

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I've completed this and I'm receiving an error when I try to run my app. It's saying user is not defined. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. This error happens because you probebly didn't logged in yet so it can't identify the user.

Comment: Still receiving an error. A server error at the if statement. Still saying user is undefined.

Comment: try now. if still getting the error. Make sure you're on the  '/' page of your sails app. If still not working try logging in first and then check to see if its working when a there is a user season.

Comment: Still the same error. Could there be something wrong with how I'm getting to the homepage? I'm just using the standard routing, and I've read a lot about serving the view up in a controller in order to see the information I'm wanting to see. Does that sound correct or have I been following the wrong rabbit hole regarding that?

Comment: Oh I got it. In your auth controller you have a function called callback.change the redirect page to a different file that has a controller attached to. Now the code should work you don't even need the if statement. This is happening because I think your homepage is out of the policy.

Comment: No... In your sails app: api/controllers you should have authController.js if you followed the tutorial I gave you earlier. In the controller you should have a callback function. Change the res.redirect(/) to some new file and make sure he got a controller attached to it. In the page put the ejs code. Now that should work

Comment: I'm having trouble finding out how to attach a controller to the file. How do you go about doing that? Also I'd like to add that I know I've asked you a lot of simple questions and I'm very appreciative of you being so patient. Thank you very much.